# How use MSAL.NET on .NET6 Application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I run Windows Form Application on .NET 6 using `Microsoft.Identity.Client` and `PublicClientAppBuilder`, but when clicked to log on ... pops up that message ...

[image]

If runs the same code on Windows Forms from .NET Framework 4.6.1 it works perfectly, but not on .NET 6.

The MSAL.NET not have support for .NET 6? or need make somes adaption to the code?

Solve that problem ... or finds alternatives solution ...

Comment: Please share the code how you build PublicClientAppBuilder.

Comment: folow on my git --> https://github.com/bpescarolli/MSAL_dotnet6

Comment: folow the version .NET Framework 4.6.1 to compare -->https://github.com/bpescarolli/MSAL_dotnetFramework461

Comment: @user2250152 folow up that two versions ... the .netFramework 4.6.1 it works , but that same code in .NET 6 is not ...

Answer (score 0):

The pop up message clearly says that, the given `redirecturi` is not supported for the current version.

- In Azure Active Directory, add the `RedirectURI` as `http://localhost`.

[image]

- Also in `Program.cs` change the `WithRedirectUri` as below.

```cs
WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
```

Same is mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#redirect-uri-for-public-client-apps), The `RedirectURI` for `.NET Core` has to be `https://localhost`. The error/alert says the same.

[image]

[image]

> The `MSAL.NET` not have support for .NET 6? or need make somes adaption to the code?

Even I do not find any official document or any code samples which explains the `.NET 6 version`.